# how get array object by name as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, for-loop

```
var index:Array = new Array;
var s:String = new String;
s = "index";
index.push("Hello");
for(var k:int=0; k<index.length; k++)
{
    trace(k);
}
```

> How do I have to modify in the line 5 index.length that s string instead utilize its index.length for example getArray(s).length instead of index.length
>   Thank You...

Comment: perfection in the details. Thanks man, very useful to me